# Ustream API to show channel Status

Tags: javascript, html, api, live-streaming

I have a need to determine whether a ustream channel is on line or offline. However I do not understand the Ustream API docs.
 I have found this http://api.ustream.tv/html/channel/all/search/title:eq:yourChannelName?key=yourDevkey in a previous post but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

replace yourChannelName with your channel name from your dashboard (dashboard -> select your channel -> info -> copy "Channel name")

or you can use our new rest api, with channel hook:
http://ustream.github.io/api-docs/channel.html#channel_hooks